# Stop Iron-Router from automatically redirecting after login

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I noticed, that either my login package or Iron-Router itself redirects you, after logging-in, to the home template. I can't seem to find any way to disable this behavior.

Packages I use, that could be related:

- iron:router
- meteorhacks:fast-render
- useraccounts:materialize
- routing
- useraccounts:core
- accounts-password

I handled the login like this:

```
unless currentUser
  +login
else
  +yield
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to handle this in your template, instead handle it directly in iron-router with an `onBeforeAction` handler in your route:

```
onBeforeAction: function(){
  if ( Meteor.userId() ){
    this.next();
  } else this.render('login');
},
```

Comment: what is `var route = ...` for? it seems to not get used here. And is it possible to change the layout template as a whole? (because there are other items, which will be hidden, if the user isn't logged in)

Comment: Sorry, that `route =` was from another function I often use. And yes, you can change the layout template as a whole in the route. I have more sample code at http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/08/meteor-build-clean-easy-to-maintain.html